# How to create a file with the name specified in ASCII encoding?

Tags: bash, filenames

I want to create a file that is called ascii 007, which is the bell symbol, which is not printable. I tried `nano $'\007'`, but that just created a file called ?; `cat ?` print the test content, that I placed in the file.

So how do I create a file, with a name set by the ascii encoding and not plainly spelled out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything has probably actually worked as you expected, but you have been misled by two different phenomena:

- `ls` and some other utilities display `?` for non-printable characters by default
- `?` is a glob that matches a single character

That results in the following behaviour:

```
$ echo foo > $'\007'
$ ls
?
$ cat ?
foo
```

So it seems like we have a file that is literally named `?`, right? Actually, that's just a happy coincidence of the two above phenomena -- the file is still called `^G`:

```
$ printf '<%q>\n' *
<$'\a'>
$ ls -lb
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 chris chris 0 Aug  1 14:20 \a
```

Probably everything worked as you expected, despite what immediately appeared to indicate that the file was literally called `?`.

Comment: The `-b` option can be used to tell `ls` to display the C-style escapes for non-printable characters.